# xcode localization only creates files for Main storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to localize my application. However when i click the project folder and choose my language i only seem to get the files on Main storyboard. As you can see below the storyboards ain't showing in the select view. Why and how can't i add the fields to the rest of my storyboards?

What i've tried so far:

`project -> Localization -> pick language`

[image]

Comment: Follow this very helpful tutorial about localisation, https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 0):

One way to localize each storyboard separately is to open up the utilities pane and click the "localize" button
[image]